# SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings with maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, slf4j, logback

I have created cutom logging in my application using - SLF4J, following the BELOW Link,

http://javaeenotes.blogspot.com/2011/12/custom-slf4j-logger-adapter.html

Its working fine with a sample HelloWorldProgram this way,

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);
        logger.info("Hello World");
    }
}
```

But if i integrate the same with my maven project , where i am using spring to create log file,

I am getting the below error.Tried many different ways to solve the issue, but no luck.

```
11:08:59,486 ERROR [STDERR] SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
11:08:59,486 ERROR [STDERR] SLF4J: Found binding in [/WEB-INF/classes/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
11:08:59,486 ERROR [STDERR] SLF4J: Found binding in [/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
11:08:59,486 ERROR [STDERR] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
11:08:59,496 ERROR [STDERR] SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.MyLoggerFactory]
```

## Pom.xml

```xml
<dependencies>

    <!-- spring core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logging dependencies -->
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.9</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <!-- Defined below -->
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <!-- Defined below -->
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion> 
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion> 
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion> 
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions> 
    </dependency>    

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xom</groupId>
                <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId>
                <artifactId>bsh-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.owasp.antisamy</groupId>
                <artifactId>antisamy</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>                        
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <classpathDependencyExcludes>
                <classpathDependencyExcludes>ch.qos.logback:logback-classic</classpathDependencyExcludes>
            </classpathDependencyExcludes>
        </configuration>
        </plugin> 
    </plugins>
</build>
```

## Logback.xml

```xml
<contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
        <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
</contextListener>


<appender name="appLogFileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            //log file creation goes here
        </rollingPolicy>        
</appender>
```

Can anyone help me in this issue?

Comment: Try to add < scope>compile</ scope> to the logback-classic dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the link given in the error message (http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings), SLF4J is designed to "*bind with **one** and **only one** underlying logging framework at a time*".

You currently have two on your classpath:

- your own custom binder (/WEB-INF/classes/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class)
- and the one from logback-classic

When SLF4J finds multiple bindings it simply randomly picks one and uses that. In your case it picked your custom binding (based on the last line of the error message "`Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.MyLoggerFactory]`"), but it is not guaranteed to do this every time.

You basically have two options:

- If you want to use your own custom binder then you should remove the logback dependencies from your POM.
- Alternatively you can obviously remove your own custom binder (but I am guessing that is not what you want).

Comment: I'm maybe missing something, but to me your two options are pretty clear, either use logback or use your custom logging. If you use your custom logging then you would remove logback completely, including its configuration. i.e. delete the logback.xml file as well. The only other possibility would be to somehow use logback without it going through SLF4J, but as far as I am aware it is not possible to use logback without using SLF4J, so that isn't going to work.